# How To get Text Area Data (Html File in Text area) using ajax And i need to send data to Php ? Ajax not sending my Text area data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

If I'm trying to send Html Data in textarea Code is failed. alert Working till Username data getting properly but ajax not sending my Data to Php server.

---

## Javascript

```
 var username=document.getElementById( "my_text" ).value;  

        if(username){

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'checkdata.php?username=username',
                    data: {
                    username:username,
                    },
                    success: function (response){
                        $( '#name_status' ).html(response);
                        if(response=="OK"){
                            return true;    

                        }
                        else{
                            return false;   
                        }
                        }
                    });
```

## Html

```
        <textarea   id="my_text"  >
                        <html>
                        <head>
                             <title>Page Title</title>
                        </head>
                            <body>
                                <h1>My First Heading</h1>
                                <p>My first paragraph.</p>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                </textarea>
```

Comment: console.log show username has a value?

Comment: Sir I'm sending Html Whole file to Ajax . All data getting in till username If condition . After that not working

Comment: My question is Ajax not working and data not send to php server. Failure at ajax

Comment: mixing of get/post ? what's on the php side ?

Comment: Not what I asked. You're sending username to ajax. Console.log(username) will show if its null or not.

Comment: Why are you adding the '?username=username' at the end of the URL? you're creating a POST header which means everything will be available in the body. You should also assign the ajax call to an eventListener. Right now the if statement is being evaluated at runtime. It's possible username doesn't have a value yet.

Comment: Daniel I got your point . But can u explain little more in coding

Comment: Sir check ajax i given properly may be my coding incorrect

Comment: Username is not null. But Ajax is problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of places your code could be breaking down. This would be easier for us to help with if you provided console logs of errors.

1) If you haven't loaded jQuery yet then the `$.ajax()` won't be called. You may also need to do `$(document).ready();` to make sure everything is loaded.

2) You are wrapping an entirely new DOM inside of a `textarea`. I'm not sure if that's a copy/paste mistake but it'll have strange effects on the result.

3) After your response it's apparent that you are actually trying to send html to the server..? Your error code from console suggests there's plenty else going on. It's hard to know how to help if we don't see everything. i.e. PHP and the rest of the client code.

<s>3) Since your `if` statement isn't wrapped in a function call it is evaluated at runtime. So the code runs at the page load but nothing triggers it later. Which means `username` is always null.</s>

<s>If you want to fix this you need something to trigger the event. You can try:</s>

## HTML

```
<body>
<textarea id='my_text'></textarea>
<button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</body>
```

## JS

```
let sub = document.getElementById('submitButton');
sub.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let username = document.getElementById('my_text').value;
  if(username){
    // Add Ajax Call Here
  }
});
```

Comment: Sir value of user i got till Ajax. Username not null. It retrieve the value properly. But Ajax only not sending my data to check data .php

Comment: add the following code before your `if` statement: `console.log(username);` and tell us what it says in the console

Comment: Sir after if statement i used alert . It showing textarea full output properly

Comment: Ok... what is the output?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
backup.php:12     <html>
    <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
                        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
                    </body>
                </html>

Comment: OutPut :- <html> <head> <title>Page Title</title> </head> <body> <h1>My First Heading</h1> <p>My first paragraph.</p> </body> </html>

Comment: Ok so you have a lot more going on than you are showing us. We need to see the PHP code and the rest of the JS/HTML. I don't see you calling `backup.php` anywhere in the code but that's your first error code

Comment: Sir Actually im trying get text area value from html and Trying to post in php through Ajax . Then i plan to write into file. Please Guide me . What is Wrong with ajax?

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND backup.php: 12 ... this means you have something else wrong. But I can't help unless you provide ALL the code.

Answer (score 0):

> Backup.html or php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Text editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function view_text () {
            var username=document.getElementById( "my_text" ).value;  
    console.log(username);
    if(username){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'checkdata.php',
                data: {
                username:username,
                },
                success: function (response){
                    $( '#name_status' ).html(response);
                    if(response=="OK"){
                        return true;    

                    }
                    else{
                        return false;   
                    }
                    }
                });

    }
    else{
        $( '#name_status' ).html("");
        return false;
    }





        }
        </script>   

</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" value="Execute >>" onclick="view_text()" class="button"/>

         <textarea   id="my_text"  >
                <html>
                <head>
                     <title>Page Title</title>
                </head>
                    <body>
                        <h1>My First Heading</h1>
                        <p>My first paragraph.</p>
                    </body>
                </html>
        </textarea>

<span id="name_status"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you loading jQuery?

Comment: your post uses jQuery.  $() and $.ajax() belong the jQuery library. But I don't see you importing jQuery anywhere. Read the first point I made in my post... if you are in fact using jQuery, but you run the code in a script tag at the start of your code then jQuery might not be available yet. you need $(document).ready()

Comment: S sir i forgot to import jquery in header.

Comment: Sorry sir it is all my mistake. I m not look properly in coding. Small mistake make big issue .

Comment: Did it fix the issue?